# MvcSiteMapProvider not updating sitemap Title

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, mvcsitemapprovider

I am currently using MVCSiteMapProvider to generate Breadcrumb for my site. I am creating site map title by passing the viewData value in the SiteMapTitle Attribute. when i first visit the links it creates the breadCrumb as required but when i try revisit any other link from my site its is showing the first visited value of Viewdata for titles.  the code looks like this

```
[SiteMapPreserveRouteData] 
    [SiteMapTitle("atlas")]
    public ActionResult Index(string id ,string Atlas)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Atlas))
        {
            ViewData["atlas"] = Atlas;
        }
        Taxonomy taxonomy = db.GetTaxonomy(new Guid(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TherapyId"]));

        var atlasList = taxonomy.GetTerms(id, 2);

        return View(atlasList);
    }
```

the Site Map Looks like this

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index" changeFrequency="Always" updatePriority="Normal" >

<mvcSiteMapNode title="Therapy"  controller="Therapy" action="Index"  >
  <mvcSiteMapNode title=""  controller="Atlas" action="Index" >
    <mvcSiteMapNode title=""  controller="Specialties" action="Index">
      <mvcSiteMapNode title=""  controller="Specialties" action="ViewImage"  />      
    </mvcSiteMapNode>        
  </mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

any Help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because of the caching implemented by the provider. You could try try setting the cacheduration (in web.config) to 0, to disable caching, but this will have a great impact on performance.

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade to MvcSiteMapProvider v4. This was a caching bug that has now been fixed. Also, you should not use the SiteMapPreserveRouteDataAttribute because it is now deprecated. For preserving route values, you should instead use preservedRouteParameters on the ISiteMapNode object.

See the blog post titled [How to Make MvcSiteMapProvider Remember a User's Position](http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/09/02/how-to-make-mvcsitemapprovider-remember-a-user-position) for examples of how to use preservedRouteParameters.